# What to import in Scala.js to use a simple "ProvidedJS" module?

Tags: scala, sbt, node-modules, scala.js

I have very simple local module exporting a class. I would like to use this module locally, using `ProvidedJS`. No matter what I have tried, each time I do `run` or `test` in sbt, the compiler complains during `fastOptJS` phase it cannot find the module.

I have verified the Javascript file is included in the `jsdeps.js` file, but no matter what I have tried writing into `@JSImport`, I always get the "Cannot find module" error.

MyTypes.js:

```
var MyType = function (x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
};

MyType.prototype.constructor = MyType;

exports.MyType = MyType;
```

build.sbt:

```
name := "JSEquals"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.12"

enablePlugins(ScalaJSPlugin)

jsDependencies += ProvidedJS / "MyTypes.js"

scalaJSUseMainModuleInitializer := true

skip in packageJSDependencies := false

//jsEnv in Compile := new org.scalajs.jsenv.nodejs.NodeJSEnv(org.scalajs.jsenv.nodejs.NodeJSEnv.Config().withArgs(List("--inspect-brk")))

scalaJSModuleKind in Compile := ModuleKind.CommonJSModule
```

MyApp.scala:

```
import scala.scalajs.js
import scala.scalajs.js.annotation._

@js.native
@JSImport("./MyTypes.js", "MyType")
class MyType(var x: Double, var y: Double) extends js.Any

object MyApp {

  @JSExport
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val my = new MyType(0, 0)
    println(s"my $my")
  }
}
```

Ready to use project available at [GitHub](https://github.com/OndrejSpanel/jsequals) in branch `minimalModule`.

What should I write into `@JSImport` to use the `MyTypes` module?

Answer (score 1):

`jsDependencies` is totally incompatible with CommonJS modules. [1] It is only (barely) working for plain old scripts that store stuff in the global scope.

When using `CommonJSModule` in Scala.js without any bundler such as scalajs-bundler, it is your responsibility to either put the `MyType.js` file in a location that can be accessed through `require('MyType.js');`, or (easier right now given the state of your project) use the complete path in `@JSImport` that gets you from the `-fastop.js` file to `MyType.js`. Given your description, it would look like

```scala
@JSImport("../../src/main/resources/MyType.js", "MyType")
```

Not pretty, and quite dependent on the specific layout, but that should get you started.

[1] https://www.scala-js.org/doc/project/module.html

Comment: I have found another variant, I am not sure which one is cleaner: `@JSImport("./classes/MyType.js", "MyType")`. SBT seems to be copying the JS files from resources to classes. It does not work without a dot, i.e.: `@JSImport("classes/MyType.js", "MyType")`, I have no idea why.

Comment: I have tried using scalajs-bundler, but it made no difference to me. I guess I must have been using it incorrectly, or misunderstanding it. Does scalajs-bundler help when I use `run` or `test` from SBT?

Answer (score 0):

There is another way, documented, which I have overlooked before: one can set `commonJSName` which will be used for node.js (i.e for SBT run / test), and avoid using `jsdeps` at all for those configuration.

See [Dependencies](https://www.scala-js.org/doc/project/dependencies.html), paragraph **CommonJS name**:

> Some (most?) JavaScript libraries try to adapt the best they can to the environment in which they are being executed. When they do so, you have to specify explicitly the name under which they are exported in a CommonJS environment (such as Node.js), otherwise they won’t work when executed in Node.js.

In my case this translates to:

```
jsDependencies += ProvidedJS / "MyTypes.js" commonJSName "MyTypes"
```

In the facade one uses `@JSGlobal`, not `@JSImport` then:

```
@js.native
@JSGlobal("MyTypes.MyType")
class MyType(var x: Double, var y: Double) extends js.Any {
```

Note: when looking for the documentation (which is easier once you know the answer), I have found [a GitHub issue](https://github.com/scala-js/scala-js/issues/2759#issuecomment-277698089) where [sjrd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1829647/sjrd) told me to use `commonJSName` in the same situation (executing tests) more than a year ago. I feel ashamed to have completely forgotten about this.